# How to update childSnapShot value in firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have two products on my product table in firebase. Here it is:

[image]

Now I want to update product_quantity when the user takes action. But when the user chooses two or more products and inputs the quantity of chosen products, only the last product quantity got replaced or updated. product selection view looks like this:
[image]
And 2nd product selection looks like this:
[image]

Here is the code for javascript:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        var uid = user.uid;
        for (var i = 0; i < itemCnt; i++) {
            var uidValueInv = $(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".uidVal").val();
            var productNameInv = $(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".productName").val();
            var amountInv = parseFloat($(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".amount").val());
            var sellingPriceInv = parseFloat($(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".sellPrice").val());
            var buyingPriceInv = parseFloat($(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".buyPrice").val());
            var quantityInv = parseFloat($(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".quantity").val()) || 0;
            var quantityCount = amountInv - quantityInv;
                                console.log(quantityCount)
            var query = firebase.database().ref("Products/").child(uid).
                        orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uidValueInv);
            query.once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                  snapshot.ref.update({
                      product_quantity: quantityCount.toString()
                  })
            })
    }
})
```

I uploaded here only firebase code, not the entire javascript how product_quantity and other stuff calculate, because those things work perfectly I checked the console that got the product_quantity perfectly. I think I just need to change in firebase update code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change below code:

```
firebase.database().ref('Products/').child(uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) 
   {
       for (var i = 0; i < itemCnt; i++) {
           var uidValueInv = $(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".uidVal").val();
           console.log(uidValueInv);
           var amountInv = parseFloat($(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".amount").val());
           var quantityInv = parseFloat($(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".quantity")
                             .val()) || 0;
           var quantityCount = amountInv - quantityInv;
           console.log(quantityCount)
           snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
               var uid_value = childSnapshot.child('uid').val();
               console.log(uid_value)
                   if (uid_value === uidValueInv) {
                       childSnapshot.ref.update({
                           product_quantity: quantityCount.toString()
                       });
                   }
            })
        }
   })
```